# Workbook should be automatically saved as a .xlsx file in user defined folder and close macro book without saving

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I recorded vba code to do some conditional formatting. The result is stored in the workbook itself. Now I want to force the user not to save the workbook, instead after the code is run, it should automatically save the workbook using  "Save As" into a non macro file using some unique identifier such as `"yyyymmmdd, hhmm.xlsx`" and it should also ask the user where to save.

Additionally, it should close the workbook without saving it and open the last saved as .`xlsx` file. I found some codes, but they are not exactly what I am looking for. Please help.

Comment: Could you post what you've attempted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
Option Explicit
Sub SaveAs()
    Dim sDate As String
    Dim FileName As String

    '// format Date
    sDate = Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD HHMM")

    '// Save As Name
    FileName = sDate

    '// Save path
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show FileName
End Sub
```

add this code below your code

---

***Per OP Comment***

This should do it - Tested on  <kbd>**Excel 2010**</kbd>

```
Option Explicit
Sub SaveAs()
    Dim xlSaveAs As String
    Dim xlPath As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '// Save As Name
    xlSaveAs = "Weekly Report - " & Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD HHMM") & ".xlsx"

    '// Save path
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    xlPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        InitialFileName:=xlSaveAs, _
        FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", _
        Title:="My Save Dialog")
        If xlPath <> False Then
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs xlPath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        Else
            MsgBox "Not Valid Path" '// Cancel
        End If

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Finally, You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Office 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814735%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN helpful.

Comment: To close the workbook without save, use
`Thisworkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False`
(full documentation on .close https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838613.aspx)

Comment: Nice @MaximePorté but I don't thing OP wants to close the workbook

Comment: if I quote the asking "Additionally, it should close the workbook without saving it and open the last saved as .xlsx file"

Comment: @MaximePorté yes `quote = close the workbook without saving it and open the last saved` so the saveAs it replaces the open workbook with new one that you just saved.

Comment: This code works! Only thing is that user has to select the save as type .xlsx from drop down option when prompted to save as. By default, it shows, .xlsm I tried changing 
     sDate = Format(Now, "YYYYMMDD HHMM") & ".xlsx"
but it doesn't help, it still saves as .xlsm file, unless chosen by user the save as type as .xlsx How to fix this?

Comment: you can use ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook to select xlsx by default, and it will ask your filepath

Comment: That worked just fine! You guys are so quick. I want to learn this stuff too. Any suggestion how I should start learning. I have extremely limited exposure to the coding world, as being a mechanical engineer. Again thank you for your help!

Comment: I changed to code to
 xlSaveAs = "Weekly Report- " & Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM") & ".xlsx"
to get the extension .xlsx however it gives run time error '1004' This extension can not be used with selected file type. Change the file extension in the File name text box or select a different file type by changing theSave as type. If I dont use ".xlsx" , then saved file becomes unreadable and asks user choose correct program to open that file.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you so much.

I tried on my own and changed liked below (which worked too.)


            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=xlPath _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Answer (score 0):

edit : I rewrite the code to do what you want

```
Public Sub SaveNewFile()
    ' Create a new file basing the name of the current file (without extension if it's an xlsm) and the creation time
    Dim filename As String
    filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").getbasename(ThisWorkbook.Name) & Format(Now, "yyyyMMdd hhmm") & ".xlsx"

    ' Save the file under the new name in xlsx format
    ' This action close the file and reopen it with the new name
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=filename, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This code works too. However, the issue is- it does not ask user where to save by opening a dialogue box. The format I am looking for is "weekly report- yyyyMMdd hhmm.xlsx"  
Instead of giving path ThisWorkbook.path, it should ask user for the path using a simple dialogue box where the path can be chosen the way path for save as operation is chosen.
Thank you for your help!